# send knockoutjs array to controller with html.beginform (and other stuff)

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a form that I need to send to a controller in mvc.  this form has regular field values mapped with a model, as well as an attachment, and knockout array.  How do I send the knockout array(taglist) back to the controller?

form snippit

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Article", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <!-- ko foreach: tagList -->
                <div class="pull-left" style="margin: 5px; border: 3px solid gray; padding: 2px;">
                    <span data-bind="text:tag"></span>
                    <span class="hidden" data-bind="text:tagid"></span> |
                    <img style="zoom:.23; margin-left:10px;"src="~/docImages/delete_remove.png" data-bind=" click: $root.tagRemove" />
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="attachedFile">Attachment:</label>
            <input class="col-md-10" type="file" name="attachedFile" id="attachedFile">
        </div>

}
```

Comment: you need to use ajax , jquery or javascript

Comment: so how would I do it with ajax.html?